# Multiply and subtract values in previous row for new row in FoxPro

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm trying to write command in fox pro that helps me calculate two variables in a table that looks like this

```
age   death_rate   alive   dead
1      0.003       1000     3
2      0.001       997      1
3      0.0006
4      0.005
5      0.002
...
```

alive at age x = (alive at age x-1) - (dead at age x-1)

dead at age x = (death_rate at age x) * (alive at age x)

I'm trying to calculate rest of the values for alive and dead automatically but the two empty columns are dependent on each other in calculation, I'm not sure how the command should look like

Comment: what is yur sql plateform?

Comment: This is very easy to do and fast in VFP. Just follow @Ed Pecyna's xBase code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot give you one command to do this, but it is relatively easy if you use a small program. I don't know what data file type you are using (VFP table, MSSQL table) so I will demonstrate with a VFP cursor. You can open a new program window in VFP by typing MODIFY COMMAND in the command window. Paste the following code in the Program window, highlight the code, right-click and Execute Selection.

```
CREATE CURSOR deathrate (age i,death_rate n(6,4),alive i, dead i)
INSERT INTO deathrate (age,death_rate,alive,dead) VALUES (1,.003,1000,3)
INSERT INTO deathrate (age,death_rate,alive,dead) VALUES (2,.001,997,1)
INSERT INTO deathrate (age,death_rate,alive,dead) VALUES (3,.0006,0,0)
INSERT INTO deathrate (age,death_rate,alive,dead) VALUES (4,.005,0,0)
INSERT INTO deathrate (age,death_rate,alive,dead) VALUES (5,.002,0,0)
GOTO 2 && you have supplied the first 2 values, go to record 2
SCATTER NAME oprev  && create a scattered object of the current record, then...
SKIP    && skip 1 record
SCAN rest
    replace alive WITH oprev.alive - oprev.dead, dead WITH round(death_rate * alive,0)
    SCATTER NAME oprev    && refresh before skipping to next record
ENDSCAN
BROWSE NORMAL LAST
```

The result is:

> ```
>       AGE DEATH_RATE       ALIVE        DEAD
>         1     0.0030        1000           3
>         2     0.0010         997           1
>         3     0.0006         996           1
>         4     0.0050         995           5
>         5     0.0020         990           2
> ```

Comment: Nice. Instead of going to record 2 you could start with an initial value too. ie: Locate
Local alive
alive = myTable.alive
Scan
 Replace alive With m.alive, dead With Round(death_rate * alive,0)
 alive = (myTable.alive-1)-(myTable.dead-1)
Endscan

Answer (score 0):

This is rather painful in Foxpro, because it does not have window functions.  You can use a cumulative `sum()` with logs and exponentiation.  So, to calculate the `alive` column:

```
select t.*,
       (select coalesce(1000 * exp(sum(log(1.0 - deathrate)), 1000)
        from t t2
        where t2.age < t.age
       ) as alive
from t;
```

You can then use a subquery to calculate the dead:

```
select t.*,
       (alive * (1 - deathrate)) as dead
from (select t.*,
             (select coalesce(1000 * exp(sum(log(1.0 - deathrate)), 1000)
              from t t2
              where t2.age < t.age
             ) as alive
      from t
     ) t;
```

Note that performance will not be very good.  I would recommend that you upgrade to a more performance database, particularly one that supports window functions.

Comment: It is not painful to do at all in VFP and doesn't need to have window functions. VFP simply supports xBase, in which this is done much easier than many. In VFP there is not coalesce() but you could use Isnull() instead. Ed Pecyna has a nice answer (although I would code a little bit different, that would do).