# Creating a Table Using Previous Values (Iterative Process)

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, database-cursor

I'm completely new to Visual FoxPro (9.0) and I was having trouble with creating a table which uses previous values to generate new values. What I mean by this is I have a given table that is two columns, age and probability of death. Using this I need to create a survival table which has the columns Age, l(x), d(x), q(x), m(x), L(x), T(x), and q(x) Where:

- l(x): Survivorship Function; Defined as l(x+1) = l(x) * EXP(-m(x))
- d(x): Number of Deaths; Defined as l(x) - l(x+1)
- q(x): Probability of Death; This is given to me already
- m(x): Mortality Rate; Defined as -LN(1-q(x))
- L(x): Total Person-Years of Cohorts in the Interval (x, x+1); Defined as l(x+1) + (0.5 * d(x))
- T(X): Total Person-Years of all Cohorts in the Interval (x, N); Defined as SUM(L(x)) [From x, N]
- e(x): Remaining Life Expectancy; Defined as T(x) / l(x)

Now I'm not asking how to get all of these values, I just need help getting started and maybe pointed in the right direction. As far as I can tell, in VFP there is no way to point to a specific row in a data-table, so I can't do what I normally do in R and just make a loop. I.E. I can't do something like:

```
for (i in 1:length(given_table$Age))
  {
  new_table$mort_rate[i] <- -LN(1-given_table$death_prop[i])
  }
```

It's been a little while so I'm not sure that's 100% correct anyway, but my point is I'm used to being able to create a table, and alter the values individually by pointing to a specific row and/or column using a loop with a simple counter variable. However, from what I've read there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in VFP, and I'm completely lost.

I've tried to make a Cursor, populating it with dummy values and trying to update each value sequentially using a SCATTER NAME and SCAN/REPLACE thing, but I don't really understand what's happening or how to fine tune this each calculation/entry that I need. (This is the post I was referencing when I tried this: [Multiply and subtract values in previous row for new row in FoxPro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133518/multiply-and-subtract-values-in-previous-row-for-new-row-in-foxpro).

So, how do I go about making a table that relies on iterative process to calculate subsequent values in Visual FoxPro? Are there any good resources that explain Cursors and the Scatter/Scan thing that I was trying (I couldn't find any resources that explained it in terms I could understand)?

Sorry if I've worded things poorly, I'm fairly new to programming in general. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest that when you ask a question that you include sample data and desired results.

Comment: VFP of course have a way to point to a specific row at any time. Also in VFP, it is possible to treat the whole table as an array and use array pointers for different rows' data. Also there are SQL and Scan...endscan. What is missing in your question is some sample data and what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can write a loop through an existing table in VFP. Use the SCAN command. However, if you're planning to add records to the same table as you go, you're going to run into some issues. Is that what you meant here? If so, my suggestion is to put the new records into a cursor as you create them and then APPEND them to the original table after you've processed all the records that were there when you started.

If you're putting records into a different table as you loop through the original, this is straightforward:

```
* Assumes you've already created the table or cursor to hold the result
SELECT YourOriginalTable && substitute in the alias/name for the original table
SCAN
  * Do your calculations
  * Substitute appropriately for YourNewTable and the two lists
  INSERT INTO YourNewTable (<list of fields>) VALUES (<list of values>)
ENDSCAN
```

In the INSERT command, if you refer to any fields of the original table, you need to alias them, like this: YourOriginalTable.YourField, again substituting appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late but maybe still helps.
The steps to achieve what you want are:
0. close the tables - just in case (see CLOSE DATABASE)

1. open the Age table (see USE in VFP help)
2. create the Survival table structure (see CREATE TABLE)
   for this you need to know the field type for each of your l(x), d(x), etc functions
   Lets say that you named the fields like your functions (i.e. Lx,Dx, etc)
3. select the Age table (see SELECT)
4. loop through Age table (see SCAN)
5. pass each record into variables (see SCATTER)
6. made your calculations starting from the Age table data (variables) using L(x),D(x),etc formulas and store it into variables named as M.**Your Survival Table Field**
   i.e. `M.mx = -LOG(1-m.Age) && see LOG`
   Note: in these calculations you can use any mix of Age table variables and the new created variables.
7. after you calculated all the fields from Survival write it into table (see APPEND && GATHER commands)
8. close the tables (see CLOSE DATABASE)